# $\lim \limits_{t \to a} \int_{c}^{d} f(t, s) ds= \int_{c}^{d} \lim \limits_{t \to a} f(t,s) ds$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

When is $\lim \limits_{t \to a} \int_{c}^{d} f(t, s) ds= \int_{c}^{d} \lim \limits_{t \to a}  f(t,s) ds$?

My guess is that $f$ uniformly continuous in a neighborhood of $(a,s)$ for $c\leq s \leq d$ is a sufficient condition for the above equality to hold. This is my try for a proof of this: for $(t,s)$ in this neighborhood we may choose $\delta >0$ such that $\left |f(t,s)-f(a,s)  \right |< \frac{\epsilon}{d-c}$ whenever $\left |(t,s)-(a,s)  \right |< \delta$. And hence in such an neighborhood \begin{align}\left |\lim \limits_{t \to a} \int_{c}^{d} f(t, s) ds- \int_{c}^{d} \lim \limits_{t \to a}  f(t,s) ds\right |&= \left |\lim \limits_{t \to a} \int_{c}^{d} f(t, s) -  f(a,s) ds\right |\\ \ \\ &\leq \lim \limits_{t \to a} \int_{c}^{d}\left | f(t, s) -  f(a,s) \right |ds\\ \ \\ &< \epsilon.\end{align} I wonder if the proof given is correct and furthermore I wonder if the assumption of $f$ uniformly continuous is needed? Can any one give an example of a continous function for which the above doesn't hold. Btw I am aware that every continous function from a compact metric space into any metric space is uniformly continous, so I understand that $f$ being continuous on a compact set is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It will be true if there exists a constant $M$ with the property that $|f(t,s)| \le M$ for all $s \in [c,d]$ and all $t$ in a neighborhood of  $a$. More generally it will be true if there is a function $g(s)$ with the property that $$\int_c^d g(s) \, ds < \infty$$ and  $|f(t,s)| \le g(s)$ for all $t$ in a neighborhood of $a$  and $s \in [c,d]$.

Comment: ok why? And can you please also comment what is wrong with my argument above?

Answer (score 1):

The neighborhood you need is of the form $(a-r,a+r)\times[c,d] $, as you need to use your estimate over the whole interval of integration. As you say, if  $f $ is continuous there, it will be uniformly continuous on the compact set where you can apply your argument. Note that  $(a-r,a+r)\times(c,d)$ is not enough: for instance take  $f (t,s)=t/s $ on $(-1,1)\times (0,1)$. Then $f $ is continuous, and $$\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_0^1f (t,s)\,ds=\infty,\ \ \lim_{t\to0^-}\int_0^1f (t,s)\,ds=-\infty,\ \ \int_0^1\lim_{t\to0}f (t,s)\,ds=0. $$